# Does it matter <strong> in <em> or <em> in <strong>?

Tags: xhtml, accessibility, semantic-markup, screen-readers

Does it matter `<strong>` in `<em>`

```
<p><strong><em>Some text</em></strong></p>
```

or `<em>` in `<strong>`?

```
<p><em><strong>Some text</strong></em></p>
```

Which is semantically correct and more accessible?

**Update:**

How screen reader would behave in both situation?

Answer (score 9):

Syntactically correct but not semantically correct. `<strong>` is an "higher order" form, so to speak, of `<em>`. If you're looking for the effect of `<b>` and `<i>`, use CSS. Remember to not choose elements because of how they look but what they mean.

Answer (score 6):

If you care about semantic meaning, you should avoid having both `em` and `strong` on an element.

> Strong: Renders as strong emphasized
>   text

([via](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_phrase_elements.asp))

If you care about valid HTML, both solutions are fine and valid.

Comment: I edited my answer. Redundency is not the best solution. If you care about default style, then you should start using a good reset css and defining everything yourself ! _edit: OP removed his comment so what I'm saying in this comment doesn't make lots of sense_

Comment: Note: If you want text bolded *and* italicised (which is what em+strong does), use either em or strong, and change their effect using CSS. That's the "clean" way...

Comment: I totally agree with @sleske, it will produce cleaner code. font-style:bold // font-decoration:italic

Answer (score 6):

Both ways you have listed are perfectly correct markup-wise, as long as you're not mixing up the order of the closing tags. This would be incorrect:

```
<p><em><strong>Some text</em></strong></p>
```

Answer (score 6):

According to [w3](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_phrase_elements.asp) `strong` is *strong emphasis*. That means that `em` and `strong` should not be used together semantically as the `strong` is already an `em`.

If you believe that strong emphasis should be bold italic I think you should just add a css declaration in which you style the strong as bold italic.

Answer (score 4):

In a visual effect perspective, it doesn't matter.

In semantic meaning, it matters since you're using emphasis and strong emphasis in the same element (Some text). It's the same as using `h1` in some places just because you want big texts and not because they're titles.

> EM: Indicates emphasis.
>
> STRONG: Indicates stronger emphasis.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html)

> The presentation of phrase elements
>   depends on the user agent. Generally,
>   visual user agents present EM text in
>   italics and STRONG text in bold font.
>   **Speech synthesizer user agents may
>   change the synthesis parameters, such
>   as volume, pitch and rate accordingly.

So beware. Use CSS to acomplish visual effects, not markup.

Comment: but if we will use css then if if css would be disabled in browser then text will not like i want

Comment: Are you really concerned about semantic/accessibility? To fully accomplish it you should separate content, presentation and behavior layers. http://titleandsummary.com/separation-of-layers-content-presentation-and-behavior/ It doesn't make sense you being afraid of screen readers and not wanting to use css, since people with screen readers aren't interested in how the text *looks*, they are interested in what text *means*.

Answer (score 2):

In (X)HTML5, the definitions/meanings are:

- [`em`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element): represents stress *emphasis* of its contents (changes meaning of sentence);
- [`strong`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element): represents strong *importance* for its contents (doesn't change meaning of sentence).

So these elements *can* be used together in principle.

To get an idea, think of reading a text out loud (depends on language, though): `em` might change the intonation (stress), `strong` might increase loudness.

I think semantically it makes no difference if you use `<strong><em>foo</em></strong>` or `<em><strong>foo</strong></em>`; at least I couldn't find anything related in the specification.