# In HTML5, is it ok to use a strong tag within an em tag?

Tags: html, accessibility, font-size, semantics

I'm currently marking up some user alerts as follows

```
<em>You are in danger of exceeding your <strong>40GB</strong> download limit</em>
```

I've found [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200590/does-it-matter-strong-in-em-or-em-in-strong) suggesting that, although valid html, this is not semantically valid. But is it really not OK to nest em/strong tags in all instances? The above example seems to me to be a perfectly reasonable use - to specifically emphasise a subsection of something that's already emphasised. But can screen readers interpret this as it's meant to be interpreted, or woudl it tend to confuse them?

Comment: just read through the answers that are provided on that question ?

Comment: @EvilP But those answers are to a question where `<strong>` and `<em>` wrap the entire text, which is obviously dubious usage, whereas my example is a bit more reasonable a use case. If I thought those answers answered my question I wouldn't have asked this one.

Comment: Unfortunately, the semantics of `<em>` and `<strong>` have changed in HTML5 from HTML4, and this may affect the answer to your question. If you are interested in HTML5, I recommend that, in particular, you read the new definition of `<em>` here : http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-em-element.html

Comment: @Alohci good point. What Doctype are we using here?

Comment: My gut feeling is that the `<strong>` here is not used to provide extra emphasis. It's not like you would raise your voice at the "40GB" when you were to say it out loud. So in this case, you shouldn't use it. A valid use would be things like `<em>You're in <strong>big</strong> trouble!</em>`. And I don't think HTML4 and HTML5 are _that_ different.

Comment: @Alohci - while someone else gave an answer that fitted my use case better, your comment is  I think a more definitive answer to the question I actually asked, so if you want to repost it as an answer I'll happily accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's permissible to use `<strong>` within an `<em>`, in terms of HTML. However, within the specific semantics of your question, it wouldn't be the best option.

Someone answered advocating using `<b>` with a great explanation of why it's appropriate and a [link to the specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-b-element.html#the-b-element) to back it up.

> The b element represents a span of text to which attention is being
>   drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance
>   and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood, such as key
>   words in a document abstract, product names in a review, actionable
>   words in interactive text-driven software, or an article lede.

But then they deleted the answer for some reason. If they want to repost their answer I'll happily upvote it and mark as the answer.

Also, for the case where you really do want to put stronger emphasis on a subsection of an alreday emphasised passage @Alohci's comment above points out that in html5 nesting `<em>` tags is permissible

> Unfortunately, the semantics of `<em>` and `<strong>` have changed in
>   HTML5 from HTML4, and this may affect the answer to your question. If
>   you are interested in HTML5, I recommend that, in particular, you read
>   the new definition of `<em>` here :
>   http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-em-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine in the case you posted, because the 'strong' part is not wrapping the whole of the text. It picks out a specific part of the text.

The problem with something like:

```
<em><strong>something</strong></em>
```

is that it, effectively, it's used to make something bold and italic. In semantics, `<strong>` overrides `<em>`, making the latter irrelevant. However, in your example, the whole thing has `<em>`, and only part of it has `<strong>` as well.

Another way of explaining it is to try reading it out loud. Can you give something both empahsis and strength? Would you be able to tell the difference between saying something with emphasis *and* saying it with strongly with emphasis? No. However, you can say something with emphasis, and in the middle of that, say something even more strongly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is almost purely theoretical, and the only practical aspect is this: are you working in a community where other authors have certain ideas about the “semantics” of the tags? In that case, it is this community’s ideas that matter, rather than the varying formulations in different HTML5 drafts.

That is, apart from adherence to some agreed coding style, it does not matter the least. In practice, all that matters is that the default rendering is italic or slanted for `em`, bold for `strong`, and by nesting them you get bold italic. Just as you would get by using `i` and `b` the same way.

Screen readers generally ignore these types of markup. It would just be too disturbing to raise the voice or change from female to male voice for individual words, with any normally used reading speed. But if screen readers react to this markup somehow, they can do that in different ways, and they will hardly try to make any fine-grained differences.

The [sample style sheet with aural features](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/aural.html#sample) in the CSS 2.1 spec is just sketchy and at most suggestive, but it may be of some relevance to note that it uses the same pitch and but higher stress and richness for `strong` (and `b`) than for `em` (and `i`) and that it has no rules where nesting would matter. That is, according to it, `strong` would be rendered the same independently of whether it is inside `em` or not.

Answer (score -2):

What you're doing is fine. You can nest tags, as long as they are correctly nested. 
This is valid:

```
<em>You are in danger of exceeding your <strong>40GB</strong> download limit</em>
```

This is not:

```
<em>You are in danger of exceeding your <strong>40GB</em></strong> download limit
```

As for semantics, you're telling the browser that some of your text should be both strong and emphasized. What this will means visually depends on the browser implementation. Emphasized is usually rendered in *italics*, which strong will be **bold**.

Comment: -1 You're not telling the browser it should be bold or italic - you're telling it that it should it be shown more strongly or with emphasis. How does a screenreader (also a browser) speak in italics?

Comment: I have this big poster in my room that says "O Lord, please help me to keep my big mouth shut until I know what I am talking about." I should probably look at it more often.