# can I put <em> tag inside <strong> tag?

Tags: css, html

This is similar to this question ([In HTML5, is it ok to use a strong tag within an em tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735928/in-html5-is-it-ok-to-use-a-strong-tag-within-an-em-tag)) but the opposite way around.

Is this okay?

```
 <p><strong>Company name <em>strapline</em></strong>email address and phone number</p>
```

I want the company name to be displayed in bold and the strapline in bold italic.

Using `strong` and `em` would save a few lines of CSS and I think it is semantic HTML. The company name is important and the strapline does need emphasising.

The code displays as I want it to, but I'm unsure if it is semantically correct or SEO friendly

Thank you

Comment: Why not just try it out? But yes, you can do that, it works :)

Comment: If it gives you the result you want, and it's valid HTML, why do you need to ask? Seems like one of those, why don't you try it type questions.

Comment: I've edited the post, see last sentance

Comment: So run it through a validator (e.g. https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). What do you expect us to do?

Comment: Thanks for the solution I'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is valid HTML. You can test it with this tool

https://html5.validator.nu